# store logo not showing in transnational order email in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, php-7

[image]

the store logo is not showing in order email which was showing and uploaded in the configuration -> design ->transnational email section

Answer (score 0):

You will need to upload your store logo for all transactional emails at **"Content --> Design --> Configuration"**. Here you need to choose your respective store/website and need to click on edit link for that particular store/website.

Once you move to edit section, at last you will find **"Transactional Emails"** tab where you need to upload logo. Please check below screenshot for your reference:

[image]

I hope this help you to get your store logo in emails. Let me know if you need any further help.

Happy to help!

Thanks,

Comment: i have alredy upload the store logo under transactional emails but still logo not showing

Comment: You might have uploaded the logo in wrong view. There are 3 views available in the "Design Configuration" grid. Those are "Default (Global) view", "Website view" and "Store view". Kindly try uploading your logo in all these views and it should work fine until and unless you have done some additional customisation or any third party extension installed which overrides this functionality.